# Show that every proper filter on a set X can be extended to a proper prime filter?

Tags: set-theory, filters

Are the following enough to complete the proof?

1. The union of a chain of filters is a filter.
2. A maximal filter is an ultra-filter.

How I can use [Zorn's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorn's_lemma) to find the maximal filter?

Comment: By *prime filter* you mean an [ultrafilter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafilter)?

Comment: Yes, both has the same definition.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have the needed ingredients, though it would be better to state 1. as: the union of a chain of *proper* filters is a *proper* filter.

Zorn's Lemma applies to a partially ordered set in which every chain has an upper bound. Here, the partially ordered set $\mathsf{P}$ is all proper filters containing a particular proper filter $F$; the ordering is set inclusion. The union of any chain in $\mathsf{P}$ is itself a proper filter containing $F$, so it's in $\mathsf{P}$, and clearly it's an upper bound of the chain w.r.t. inclusion. So Zorn's Lemma applies to $\mathsf{P}$, and you can conclude that a maximal element of $\mathsf{P}$ exists. Such a maximal element is a maximal filter, which, as you note, is an ultrafilter. QED.